# javax.faces.ViewState parameter duplication in POST request after ajax render

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2.2, viewstate, mojarra

I'm not a pro in jsf and i have a problem. After ajax render was triggered, I received two javax.faces.ViewState parameters with different values in the POST request. What could be the cause of this and is it possible to fix it?
In my project: javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD is server.
Thank you!

Comment: There are 4 forms on my page

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.